# batch file get filename and rename it

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

what is the command in batch file get file name and rename it.

ex: in c:\temp\ folder I have found.txt

output:
c:\temp\found_092513.txt

Best Regards,
Ryl

Comment: `REN "c:\temp\found.txt" "found_092513.txt"`

Comment: need also the command to get the filename with extension name

Comment: You are close to a -1! What is "extension name"? Write a clear question!

Comment: Opps sorry I rephrase my question.

Comment: Where did you get `_092513`? Is this literally?

Comment: _092513 is just a sample output filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost sure that this isn't what you pretend, but that's what you're asking:

```
FOR %%i IN (C:\temp\*.*) DO ECHO REN "%%~i" "%%~ni_092513%%~xi"
```

Check output and remove `ECHO` to make it work.

Comment: if "092513" will be the system date what I need to add?

Comment: You may put that suffix in a variable `SET suffix=092513` and replace target with `"%%~ni_%suffix%%%~xi"`. To dynamically get date, search for it - it is a recurrent question.